# Why do I get "a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice" when creating a new column with apply?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have something like this,

```py
df1 = ...
df1['NEW_COLUMN'] = df1['SOME_COLUMN'].apply(lambda x: ...)
```

Although this works and I get the column 'NEW_COLUMN' added to the dataframe, I get this following annying warning. Why? And what is the solution?

```py
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Comment: Is this helping? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Well, I just want some easy solution to this problem, rather than going into the intrincacies of dataframes, like the answers on those post do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to avoid getting warned, you can set it in pandas options. If you understand why the warning is, and why is it happening then you can simply ignore it by adding this after importing pandas:

`pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`

Answer (score 1):

Add `copy()` to avoid getting this warning

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Value" : [0.12,0.22,0.32,0.11,0.54,0.55,0.98]})
df['Category'] = df.Value.apply(lambda x: 'Neg' if x < 0.5 else 'Pos').copy()
```

Comment: It is from Pandas docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html should not make much difference.